# C# Console Application to launch instances of itself on all monitors

Tags: c#, .net, console, console-application

I have a C# console application that I want to execute on all monitors, instantly full screened.

I have the full screen working via SendKeys.SendWait().

Its a fairly light app so if having multiple instances running is required thats not a big deal.

Things I have tried: using SendKeys.Send(), a AutoHotKey script to open the application and shift to a second monitor. No luck on either routes. Would prefer this to be a all in one solution but whatever works.

I assume this will have to be done off Main() so here is that:

```
 static void Main()
        {
            
            Console.SetWindowSize(Console.LargestWindowWidth, Console.LargestWindowHeight);
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("matrix");

            foreach (Process proc in processes)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                SendKeys.SendWait("{F11}");
            }

            Console.ForegroundColor = NormalColor;
            Console.WindowLeft = Console.WindowTop = 0;
            Console.WindowHeight = Console.BufferHeight = Console.LargestWindowHeight;
            Console.WindowWidth = Console.BufferWidth = Console.LargestWindowWidth - 3;
            Console.SetWindowPosition(0, 0);
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            int width, height;
            int[] y;
            Initialize(out width, out height, out y);//Setting the Starting Point
           
            while (true)
            {
                Counter = Counter + 1;
                UpdateAllColumns(width, height, y);
                if (Counter > (3 * Interval))
                    Counter = 0;

            }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The easiest way, just mirror your monitors and have it running in only one! No additional code needed!

Comment: Thanks for this idea, that might be a viable option. Do you have any idea how to set all monitors to become mirrored in C#? An ideal situation would be to have a single exe file which handles everything & then reverts all changes when closed.

Comment: My idea is having this set in your OS, like windows, where you just configure to mirror one screen to all monitors, if that's not viable for you because you want to have different views in the monitors and ONLY share this console application between them, then it's more difficult, but I personally would look in the "standard output" aka (stdout) in C#.

Comment: Apologize for lack of clarity regarding intentions: This application is being developed for Windows 10 Pro using Visual Studio 2019 with C# and the latest version of the .NET framework. For me personally, both monitors in question are identical units. But it would be better to work on all monitors regardless of size, ect. Having a mirror trick for one screen to show on the rest is perfectly acceptable and probably ideal. I will read some documentation about stdout soon, thank you!

Comment: I guess I should also mention project goals: I have the Matrix waterfall effect working in a console application, automatically opening up in full screen. The goal is to have it display on all monitors and to then disable all keyboard input. Closing the application completely when a special defined key combo is pressed. Effectively making my own lock screen.